# Adaboost with neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, adaboost

I implemented Adaboost for a project, but I'm not sure if I've understood adaboost correctly. Here's what I implemented, please let me know if it is a correct interpretation.

1. My weak classifiers are 8 different neural networks. Each of these predict with around 70% accuracy after full training.
2. I train all these networks fully, and collect their predictions on the training set ; so I have 8 vectors of predictions on the training set.

Now I use adaboost. My interpretation of adaboost is that it will find a final classifier as a weighted average of the classifiers I have trained above, and its role is to find these weights. So, for every training example I have 8 predictions, and I'm combining them using adaboost weights. Note that with this interpretation, the weak classifiers are not retrained during the adaboost iterations, only the weights are updated. But the updated weights in effect create new classifiers in each iteration.

Here's the pseudo code:

```
all_alphas = [] 
all_classifier_indices = []
initialize all training example weights to 1/(num of examples)
compute error for all 8 networks on the training set
for i in 1 to T:
      find the classifier with lowest weighted error.
      compute the weights (alpha) according to the Adaboost confidence formula
      Update the weight distribution, according to the weight update formula in Adaboost.
      all_alphas.append(alpha) 
      all_classifier_indices.append(selected_classifier)
```

After `T` iterations, there are `T` alphas and `T` classifier indices ; these `T` classifier indices will point to one of the 8 neural net prediction vectors.

Then on the test set, for every example, I predict by summing over `alpha*classifier` .

I want to use adaboost with neural networks, but I think I've misinterpreted the adaboost algorithm wrong..

Comment: So .. what actually happens?

Comment: @javadba The accuracy more or less remains the same.. I haven't used boosting before, and I've read that it does always add 1 to 2% to the accuracy..

Comment: another question , In adaboost procedure, the base/meta classifier must support sample_weight attribute. but Nerual network the weight is update through SGD or some other optimizer. How to add sample-weight to Nerual network

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Boosting summary:

1- Train your first weak classifier by using the training data

2- The 1st trained classifier makes mistake on some samples and correctly classifies others. Increase the weight of the wrongly classified samples  and decrease the weight of correct ones. Retrain your classifier with these weights to get your 2nd classifier.

In your case, you first have to resample with replacement from your data with these updated weights, create a new training data and then train your classifier over these new data.

3- Repeat the 2nd step T times and at the end of each round, calculate the alpha weight for the classifier according to the formula.
4- The final classifier is the weighted sum of the decisions of the T classifiers.

It is hopefully clear from this explanation that you have done it abit wrongly. Instead of retrain your network with the new data set, you trained them all over  the original dataset. In fact you are kind of using random forest type classifier (except that you are using NN instead of decision trees) ensemble.

PS: There is no guarantee that boosting increases the accuracy. In fact, so far all the boosting methods that I'm aware of were unsuccessful to improve the accuracy with NN as weak learners (The reason is because of the way that boosting works and needs a lengthier discussion).

Comment: Thanks, I instead used the weights given by adaboost directly in the loss function.. The loss is now weighted for each training example, with weights coming from adaboost

Comment: even better. It is the exact implementation and also if you want to generalize it to multiclass boosting it is easier.

Comment: @TNM another question , In adaboost procedure, the base/meta classifier must support sample_weight attribute. but Nerual network the weight is update through SGD or some other optimizer. How to add sample-weight to Nerual network

Comment: Now a days it is pretty easy. Almost all deep learning framework support sample weights. Anyhow, if you want to implement it by yourself, the easiest way is to draw training samples according to the sample weights (with replacement) and pass it to your network

Comment: @sanjeevmk can you please give some explanation, how you relate adaboost to keras loss function.

Comment: I would be very grateful for a demonstration too.