# How to add scikit-kearn based loss to neural network?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to train a neural network that has a loss component coming from an AdaBoost classifier.

```
myLoss(y_true, y_pred, adaClf, Z_):
    loss = BinaryCrossEntropy(y_true, y_pred) + MeanSquareError(adaClf.predict(Y_pred), Z_)
    return loss
```

where `adaClf` is the scikit-learn classifier. How can I implement this in Keras?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you can not use external functions as loss in tensorflow. With `tf.map` you can use external functions, but no gradients can flow through it and you definitely need gradients in your loss. So you probably have to implement the classifier in tensorflow. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691636/adaboost-with-neural-networks) helps you.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the clarification, I really need a boosted decision tree.

Comment: The decision tree only gives me the correct labels, the loss function should still be differentiable. So I think it's possible in tensoflow to do this.

Comment: Yeah that is right, but in that case I would suggest you use the tf.dataset API. You can load the input image and directly calc the label with `tf.map`. You can also do it at runtime like in your code, but performance wise I would do it with tf.dataset.